# Problems accessing camera in react native on iphone

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to access the camera on an iphone and I don't know how to do it.

I have a `<button>` that on click I want to access camera on an iphone.

Can someone explain to me how do I can do this, please?

Comment: You need to find a RN Camera library or make one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `import Camera from 'react-native-camera';`

then create a method,

```
takePicture() {
    this.camera.capture()
      // some service action if you want to use... 
      .then(data => {
        .........
      // this is for vibrating device while taking photo
        Vibration.vibrate();
        ..........
      });
  }
```

you need to add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />




async function requestCameraPermission() {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
          {
            'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
            'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                       'so you can take awesome pictures.'
          }
        )
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          alert("You can use the camera")
        } else {
          alert("Camera permission denied");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err)
      }
    }
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera

that is all you need to do ...

Comment: I have a doubt. For IOS I use the same as you are showing to me? @Vijay help me

Comment: does not works. get this error 'Aspect' of undefined